# API which creates full crash dump

Tags: crash-reports, crash-dumps, windows-error-reporting

I would like to know if there is any API available which would create the full crash dump.

Currently, i'm using the [MiniDumpWriteDump()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms680360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API with [MiniDumpWithFullMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms680519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
But, I am not getting much information to analyze from the dump created.

Comment: What does "I am not getting much information to analyze from the dump created." actually mean?  What is it you're looking for and not getting?

Comment: The call stack and the memory information shown in the dump captured using "MinidumpWriteDump" is not helpful in analyzing the crash issue.

Comment: What would be helpful to analyze the crash issue?

Comment: You have the correct API and the correct setting. If you can't get the necessary information out of it, that's a different case. What tool are you using to analyse the crash dump? WinDbg? What programming language do you use? C++ works nice with WinDbg, for C# you need a plugin called SOS. If you don't use SOS, you'll not get .NET callstacks.

Answer (score -1):

You said that you need a call stack and memory information -- both useful things for debugging =)!

**The Call Stack**

It's helpful to know how the call stack gets created from your crash dump file. This is a quote from MSDN on how a call stack gets generated, I took out the points I found most relevant here, but it's worth the full read [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416588(v=vs.85).aspx):

- When you are debugging an application that has crashed, the debugger
  attempts to show you the functions on the stack that led up to the
  crash. Without a PDB file, the debugger can not resolve the function
  names, their parameters, or any local variables that are stored on
  the stack.
- If functions on the current stack were compiled by using the Omit
  Frame Pointers (/Oy) optimization, and if symbols are not present,
  the debugger cannot reliably determine which function called the
  current function.
- If you see a warning about missing symbols, or no symbols loaded,
  ...do not trust the stack from that point down.
- Even if a library that is in your call stack doesn't have PDBs
  available, as long as they were compiled with frame pointers, the
  debugger should be able to guess correctly at the parent functions.
  Starting with Windows XP Service Pack 2, all Windows DLL and
  executable files are compiled with FPO disabled...On versions of
  Windows before Windows XP SP2, all operating system binaries require
  matching symbol files that contain FPO information, to allow accurate
  debugging and profiling.
- If you debug 64-bit native executables, you do not need symbol files
  to produce valid stack traces, because x64 operating systems and
  compilers are designed not to require them. However, you still need
  symbol files to retrieve the function names, call parameters and
  local variables.

I would still look into Windows Error Reporting, which you're actually already using (the API) -- specifically setting up Local Crash Dumps. You can turn them on with a registry key and then enable "Full Dumps" by setting the DumpType=2. If you need to generate a crash dump file from code I would try the optimizations [on this MSDN article about crash dump analysis](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416349(v=vs.85).aspx).

See [Collecting User-Mode Dumps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181(v=vs.85).aspx) for more information about setting up local crash dumps with a registry setting -- or try the optimizations in the crash dump analysis file -- and make sure you have your PDBs =).

Happy debugging.